Django renaming log level to 3 character format
In python, using logging module, the log level format can be changed with:
logging.addLevelName(logging.DEBUG, 'DBG')

How can I do it in Django?
My (working) logging configuration in settings.py:
LOGGING: dict[Any, Any] = {
'version': 1,

'formatters': {
    'app_log_format': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    },
},

'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': current_log_path,
        'formatter': 'app_log_format',
    },
},

'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},

}
Thanks

It seems dictConfig format from logging.config does not provide this setting (Django logging config is based on this setting format).
Try to set your custom level name directly in wsgi.py or in asgi.py before the application is instantiated.
